# Display spinner with jQuery-ui autocomplete

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've been searching all over the place and just don't see anyone doing it - Is it possible to have some kind of spinner/loader with a jQuery UI Autocomplete? (1.8) while data is being fetched?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should be able to put a spinner image next to the field with the autocomplete and hide it initially.  Then use the callback functions to hide/show it.

Then use the search option to show the spinner and open to hide it:

v1.8 and below

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   search: function(event, ui) { 
       $('.spinner').show();
   },
   open: function(event, ui) {
       $('.spinner').hide();
   }
});
```

v1.9 and up

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   search: function(event, ui) { 
       $('.spinner').show();
   },
   response: function(event, ui) {
       $('.spinner').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is the spinner is not hidden if the response contains zero results because open event doesn't get generated in that case. The control should really have a "search completed" event to be called irrespective of result count. The planning wiki http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137709/Autocomplete makes reference to such an event called "response" but it doesn't seem have been implemented yet.

Comment: Apprently jQuery UI 1.9 includes a fix for this issue http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6777

Comment: Event "open" - not a good idea. The best way to use "response", because if autocomplete haven't return any data then "open" haven't invoke, but "response" invoke.

Comment: Correct, when I answered this the "response" event was not available.  I'm editing the above answer to include the new way to do this.

Comment: still the way to go. In my case the other answer were not applicable as I needed styling for the parent element

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Been searching for so long and this was the only one that gave me the result I wanted - Even after so many years later!

Answer (score 48):

My solution was to use the .ui-autocomplete-loading CSS class that gets added and removed on the input element while the ajax GET request is in process:

```
input[type='text'].ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: url('/icons/loading.gif') no-repeat right center;
}
```

Granted it's not a very flexible solution since you can't display the spinner outside the input element but in my case it's exactly the UX I was looking for.

Comment: I tried this and it ALMOST worked. It's changing the entire background to the spinner, which is not good when the background is a different color (ie: white textbox on blue background).  I used the following:
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background-image: url('/Content/Images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right center;
}

Answer (score 7):

**CSS Solution**

If the loading element is a sibling of the input control then CSS general sibling combinator (~) can be used:

```css
.loading {
    /* whatever */
}
#autocomplete.ui-autocomplete-loading ~ .loading {
    background-image: url(loading.gif);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html#example-5)
[**Alternate (jQuery) solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Ad95A/27/)

Answer (score -3):

```
input[type='text'].ui-autocomplete-loading {

background:  url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif')          no-repeat
 right center;

}
```