# Adding a preloader to jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, preloader

I am using Jquery's autocomplete to retrieve a list of options from the mysql database and output them on search. But sometimes it takes a minute so I would like to add a small preloading gif when the search query is entered. I have searched google and here, and have not found the answer I need. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated! here is my code:

JQUERY:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#keywords").autocomplete({
    source: keywordList,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#keywords").val(ui.item.value);
        } 
  });
});
</script>
<?php echo keywordArray(); ?>
```

//This is retrieving the array from database and outputting it, here is the code to do that:

```
    function keywordArray()
{
  $rsKeywords = mysql_query("SELECT Destination FROM Destinations WHERE Country = 'Mexico'");

  $output = '<script>'."\n";
  $output .= 'var keywordList = [';

  while($row_rsKeywords = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsKeywords))
  {
    $output .= '"'.$row_rsKeywords['Destination'].'",';
  }

  $output = substr($output,0,-1); //Get rid of the trailing comma
  $output .= '];'."\n";
  $output .= '</script>';
  return $output;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="keywords" name="keywords" type="text" autocomplete="off" size="40" >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your css add this:

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading { background:url('img/indicator.gif') no-repeat right center }
```

replace `img/indicator.gif` by your image preload path, you can also change `right` by `left` if you want the preload to be in the left side

js:

```
$("#keywords").autocomplete({
    source: keywordList,
    minLength: 2,

    search  : function(){$(this).addClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');},
    open    : function(){$(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');},

    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#keywords").val(ui.item.value);
        }
```

Comment: did not work.. I added it to the css and nothing happens in the input field.. thanks for the try though!

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly :)

Comment: do i hav to add this in jquery-ui.css file?..if so its not working..and i couldnt find a class like that..i m using jQuery UI - v1.9.2 version..

Comment: @Lakshmanan please check this [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519513/spinner-with-jquery-ui-1-8-autocomplete)